# Add Class/ Remove Class to header

Tags: jquery

Hey trying to hide the menu when user clicks on the modal trigger and remove the hide class when another trigger is clicked. The header def gets removed when you click on the modal trigger but when you click the closed button the menu doesn't reappear. I don't think the HTML matters for this question but let me know if  should provide it.

My CSS:

```
.hide {
display: none;
}
```

My jQuery:

```
   $(window).load(function(){
        $(".modal-pop").click(function() {
          $("#myModal").modal();
            $("#header").addClass("hide");
          });
      $("close").click(function() {
        $("#header").removeClass("hide");
    });
  });
```

Comment: `$('close')` is looking for `<close>`.

Comment: `$("close")` should be changed to `$("#close")` or `$(".close")` based on whether it is ID or class.

Comment: This should be closed as typographycal error (offtopic in stackoverflow)

Answer (score 1):

I think it's a simple typo that you are missing `.` before class selector.

```
$(".close").click(function() {
    $("#header").removeClass("hide");
});
```

Comment: Hey thanks! Def overlooked this.

Comment: see now the problem is that when i click outside the modal the menu stays hidden, how would i go abouts fixing this? When i target the close button the menu appears again. Should I target the body?

Comment: @carlcreative can you share code in fiddle?

Comment: @carl: that would be a different problem, and unrelated to this one. In which case please search for an existing solution, or ask a new question (if an existing duplicate isn't found).